# Play JSON: How to use string as proper json

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
    val json = JsObject(Seq(
        "type" -> toJson("filter"),
        "params" -> toJson(fP.parseToJson())
    )).toString()
```

fP.parseToJson() produces a json string which is used in other places in the code.

I get this:

```
{
  type: "filter",
  params: "{"searchId":"","client":"ios","lat":40.743894995835525,"lon":-74.00080404533901,"radius":20.0}"
}
```

I want to get:

```
{
  type: "filter",
  params: {
    "searchId":"", 
    "client":"ios",
    "lat":40.743894995835525,
    "lon":-74.00080404533901,
    "radius":20.0
  }
}
```

Ultimately the question is: Is there a way to take a string that's already json and utilize it as a json object in the json response?

Comment: What's the difference between those two JSON snippets, other than the second is pretty-printed?

Comment: @HotLicks - Quotes.  In the first case, `params` is a string containing JSON data.  In the second, it's a data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.parse takes care of it apparently.

```
val json = JsObject(Seq(
    "type" -> toJson("filter"),
    "params" -> Json.parse(fP.parseToJson())
)).toString()
```